# Glide with Firebase - Load failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm getting a load failed log from Glide and the Exception in the Listener is null.

```
StorageReference firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
StorageReference imageReference = firebaseStorage.child("/Folder1/"
            + id + ".png");

Glide.with(context)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(imageReference)
            .asBitmap()
            .override(300, 300)
            .animate(R.anim.fade_in)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(view);
```

If I do this format, it works:

```
storageRef.child("/Folder1/" + id + ".png").getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        // Use the bytes to display the image
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Why doesn't Glide work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Firebase 10.2.6 was an issue. I reverted to 10.2.1 and it works.